# Equality between linear span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $S$ and $T$ subsets of V, vector space. If $S \subset T$ then $span(S) \subset span(T)$

I need help guys! Can you help me please?

Comment: Your last three questions have been closed as off-topic. Please read the reasons listed on each of these, and improve your questions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v \in $span$(S)$, then $v$ is a linear combination of elements from $S$, like $v=\sum v_is_i$, where $v_i$ are scalars and $s_i$ are elements of $S$. Now, $S$  is a subset of $T$, which means that the $s_i$ are also in $T$, which means that $v$ is a linear combination of elements from $T$, so $v \in $span$(T)$, so span$(S) \subset $ span$(T)$.

Comment: Please consider not giving such a complete answer to questions posed like this - it only encourages posters to continue dumping problems with absolutely no thoughts and efforts of their own here (as has happened *several* times with this OP).

Comment: Sorry  about this.This will be the last time I do anything similar.

Comment: Well, this feels bad.